# No suitable method found for makeText

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I seem to be getting this error, I'm new to Android Studio and I'm trying to get names from an array into a `ListView` then when user taps on the any of the list a `Toast` is activated. But I seem to be stuck with this error below:

```
error: no suitable method found for makeText(MainActivity,Object,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to CharSequence)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to int)
```

Here's my code:

```
final ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
names.add("Samuel");
names.add("Manuel");
names.add("King");

listv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, names.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(names.get(position)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your `ArrayList` is defaulting to the type `Object` because you didn't specify `String` when you instantiated it. If this is true then when you call `names.get(position)` it would be returning you an `Object` instead of a `String` which is causing a problem for you because the `Toast.makeText()` method is expecting arguments of types `(Context,CharSequence,int)` rather than what you are passing it which is `(Context,Object,int)`

*Note that `CharSequence` and `String` can be treated as the same for your purposes in this case.*

If this theory is correct you could resolve the problem a few different ways.

1. you could call `toString()` to explicitly convert your object to a string. Like this:

   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, names.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

or 2) you could declare the type of `String` when you initialize your `ArrayList` Like this:

```
final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

then your call of `names.get(position)` should be returning a `String` instead of an `Object`

Answer (score 0):

In `Toast` class there is no method `makeText(MainActivity, Object, int)` with this arg that is the reason you are getting this error.